# Porting SQLite View to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sqlite, view

I have to "port" an SQLite database to MySQL. The database is set up from a C# application with the Connector/NET lib.

Porting the methods for creating the tables of the DB was straight forward, but I got stuck at a view.

The SQLite code for the view works just fine and looks like the following:

```
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS EXO_ResultsSummaries AS 
SELECT ParticipantBIB, 
       t.HeatIndex, 
       (CASE WHEN t.QualiGroup IS NULL THEN t.Finals ELSE t.QualiGroup END) AS HeatLevel, 
       PointsObstacle0 + PointsObstacle1 AS TotalScore, TimeObstacle0 + TimeObstacle1 AS TotalTime  
FROM (EXO_Results INNER JOIN Heats ON EXO_Results.HeatIndex = Heats.HeatIndex) t 
WHERE t.Completed = 1;
```

Since the "IF NOT EXISTS" statement does not work with MySQL, I changed the code to the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW EXO_ResultsSummaries AS
SELECT ParticipantBIB, 
    t.HeatIndex, 
    (CASE WHEN t.QualiGroup IS NULL THEN t.Finals ELSE t.QualiGroup END) AS HeatLevel, 
    PointsObstacle0 + PointsObstacle1 AS TotalScore, TimeObstacle0 + TimeObstacle1 AS TotalTime  
FROM (EXO_Results INNER JOIN Heats ON EXO_Results.HeatIndex = Heats.HeatIndex) AS t 
WHERE t.Completed = 1;
```

However, if I try to create the view from my application (or from the workbench), I get this error:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS t  WHERE t.Completed = 1' at line 6
```

Comment: No need for the parentheses and the `as t` alias, since there is no derived table in the from clause, just a simple join. Obviously, you need to remove any reference to the t alias from the select list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately I get this error if I do as you say:
MySqlException: Column 'HeatIndex' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: You need to define from which table the quey should puck that column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Shadow for his comments. Changed my code accordingly and this worked just fine:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW EXO_ResultsSummaries AS SELECT ParticipantBIB, 
Heats.HeatIndex, 
(CASE WHEN Heats.QualiGroup IS NULL THEN Heats.Finals ELSE Heats.QualiGroup END) AS HeatLevel, 
PointsObstacle0 + PointsObstacle1 AS TotalScore, TimeObstacle0 + TimeObstacle1 AS TotalTime  
FROM EXO_Results INNER JOIN Heats ON EXO_Results.HeatIndex = Heats.HeatIndex  
WHERE Heats.Completed = 1;
```